# Filtering to Calculate Multiple x-intercepts using R Studio

Tags: r, filter, ggplot2, intercept

I have a data set called `alprazolam.df` that looks like:

```
Sample.Name    Component.name  TCAmount  Ratio
1A-S0            Alprazolam      0.0      0.05
1A-S1            Alprazolam      1.5      0.07
1A-S2            Alprazolam      3.1      0.08
1A-S3            Alprazolam      6.25     0.10
2A-S0            Alprazolam      0.0      0.06
2A-S1            Alprazolam      1.5      0.08
2A-S2            Alprazolam      3.1      0.09
2A-S3            Alprazolam      6.25     0.10
1B-S0            Alprazolam      0.0      0.05
1B-S1            Alprazolam      1.5      0.08
1B-S2            Alprazolam      3.1      0.10
1B-S3            Alprazolam      6.25     0.11`
```

Right now I am plotting the data using the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(alprazolam.df, aes(x=TCAmount, y=Ratio, shape=alprazolam.df$Sample.Name)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=alprazolam.df$Sample.Name), size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15:19)) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, level=0.95, se=FALSE,
    aes(colour=alprazolam.df$Sample.Name)) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Amount (ng/mL)") +
  ylab("Response Ratio")
```

This allows me to plot multiple sets of data on the same graph where it has been filtered by the `Sample.Name` which is awesome.

Now I need added to the graph (or printed beneath!) the y=mx+b equation/R^2 coefficient for EACH of the lines generated. Most important, I need to compute and have the x-intercept displayed for each line fitted in the ggplot (again I'm not fussy if it is on the graph or beneath it).

Outside of ggplot you can see the problem using:

```
alprazolam.fit <- coef(lm(Ratio~TCAmount, data=alprazolam.fit))
eint <- alprazolam.fit[1] / alprazolam.fit[2]
```

is that this doesn't discriminate based on Sample.Name but applies a linear model across all sample sets. If there is a way to add some kind of loop which will filter based on the different `Sample.Name`'s, calculate lm and the x-int for each and then print out the set of y=mx+b and x-int that I'm after, that would also work perfectly great as well.

Comment: There is no 'Sample.Name' in your sample data. Furthermore, do not use 'df$variable` inside aes-calls. They are unneccessary and can lead to unexpected issues when used in functions. Finally, it's often easier to calculate data outside ggplot and then use geom_text or similar.

Comment: Hi Heroka. I've updated the Sample.Name issue you highlighted if you are able to answer my question with that. Also - do you have a way of suggesting how to avoid using df$variable? The purpose of doing this has been to colour code my data sets according to the Sample.Name.

Comment: you avoid df$variable the same way you assign `x` and `y`. Just use `aes(color=variable)`. The variable gets evaluated within the data.frame that you feed in the initial ggplot call.

Comment: Thanks Matt74. Would you have suggestions for following up with what Heroka said as well about accomplishing this calculation outside ggplot and then moving it in? How can I create what I think will have to be a loop to calculate all the associated x-intercepts?